# knockout observable array push adding only first object

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have an observable array. Assume that (object) data has Id, Name, Description

```
self.SelectedObjects =  ko.observableArray();
self.SelectedObjects.push(data);
self.SelectedObjects.push(data);
```

Line number 1 and 2 work fine. 
At line number 3 the debug point vanishes and never comes back.

Comment: Your code should just work, something else is happening in your code which make this question impossible to answer. Please add more context   to your question! Maybe in a JSFiddle which reproduces your problem...

Comment: open javascript console. Do you have any errors here?

Comment: Thank you for a very quick response. I think you are right and your hint helped, something else is happening. Not able to find so far but will update once I find out.

Answer (score 1):

this simple example works well, may be problem somewhere else

```
var viewModel = new function()
{
    var self = this;
    var data = {"id" : "id1", "name" : "name1"};
    self.SelectedObjects =  ko.observableArray();
    self.SelectedObjects.push(data);
    self.SelectedObjects.push(data);
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t2aPY/)